# Swift MPRemoteCommandCenter nextTrackCommand gets called 3 times

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I am using MPRemoteCommandCenter to change song in my music radio app. But when I press next track button from lock screen it jumps 3 steps insted of one.

Here is my code:

```
func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { [unowned self]     event in
        print("Next")
        self.stationIndex = (self.stationIndex+1)
        self.currentStation = self.stations[self.stationIndex]
            return .success
        }
}
```

The output is:
Next
Next
Next

But I only press the button once. What can I do to only output it once insted of 3 times?

Comment: Any chance that `setupRemoteTransportControls` itself is getting called more than once?

Comment: Thank you, that is correct.

Comment: Cool, I'll give it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is likely that you are calling `setupRemoteTransportControls` multiple times. Every time you do, you call `commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget` and set up a new action-target pair (without removing the existing one). So when the user presses the button, all of those pairs fire.

Comment: Hello matt, If I mention setupRemoteTransportControls only in my homeController then it works for all viewcontrollers ?